# C++ using variables between cpp files when extern is returning errors

Tags: c++, extern

What I'd like to do is use glUseProgram(); which is an OpenGL function
however too use it returns problems....

Why?

Because apparently even when declaring a seperate header file 
with an declared extern variable then using it in my main.cpp file 
and user-defined OpenGL Engine structure definition gives me errors 
with MSVC 2013

Here is a test case using only generic c++:

**variable_header.hpp**

```
        extern int ProgramID = whateverfunctionyouwant();
```

**OGL_Engine.hpp**

```
     #ifndef __OGL_ENGINE_HPP__
     #define __OGL_ENGINE_HPP__

        struct OGL_Engine {
          int Setup();
          int ShaderSetup();
        };

     #endif
```

**OGL_Engine.cpp**

```
 #ifndef __OGL_ENGINE_CPP__
 #define __OGL_Engine_CPP__
       int OGL_Engine::Setup(){
            int whatever = 0;
       }

       int OGL_Engine::ShaderSetup(){
           int readfile = 0;
           afunctionyouwant(ProgramID);
       }
    #endif
```

The errors I get are :

> Error 3   error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

This happens in my original files, not test case but it should say this I hope.

Comment: typically, `extern` variables are declared in headers and defined in source files. Try moving the definition and initialization to a source file.

Comment: I tried that with main.cpp and OGL_Engine.cpp both returning an error however I'll try it again...

Comment: Yep undeclared indentifier ...

Comment: It doesn't look like you have any include guards in `variable_header.hpp`.  Do you have them in the original?  Please include a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with the exact error message(s) you get when you try to build the MCVE.

Comment: I can't edit too add the main.cpp unforchunately ... -__- 

But I've added the header guards too variable_header.hpp going to see if that works probably won't.

Comment: Yey what a surprise still :

Error 3 error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not define a variable in header file, or you will get the above error if you include such header file in multiple source files.

```
extern int ProgramID = whateverfunctionyouwant();
```

Just use **extern** to declare it

```
extern int ProgramID;
```

and then define it in one of source file

Comment: Jacky I'm getting this error message :

Error 4 error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

I wanna assume that this is due too the way I defined it if for example I do 
[variable header.hpp]
extern int programID;

[ogl_engine.cpp header]
programID = whateverfunctiontouseprogramID();


but apparently that's not good enough... hmm

Comment: You still have not defined it. Since your included header declares it as extern, the assignment does not actually allocate the variable.

Comment: Okay got it too work somewhat had to do the type name and value not just the name and value in the cpp files that needed to use it.

Comment: Correct. The type is what makes a declaration as opposed to an assignment.

Comment: @DominicHughes  Define it in a source file like **int ProgramID = 89;**

Comment: Wait if my opengl struct is returning programID then will that still work even with all these new definitions on every cpp file with the extern declaration header file. Mad Physicist or Jacky

Comment: See my answer. The struct does not return anything. If you are asking about using `ProgramID` as I see you doing, the `extern` declaration will enable you to do that.

Comment: well lets just say that it does return programID then what would I need to do for it too work because currently nadda is showing on the framebuffer and I am certain it's because of glUseProgram(); 

I'll upvote his answer as well oh wait I can't what a surprise.

Comment: Did you include `variable_header.hpp` anywhere so that it ends up in the cpp file?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply I'll check now, 
yes it is in my main.cpp  and OGL_Engine.cpp . Mad Physicist

Answer (score 1):

Two things to keep in mind here:

1. When you include a header file, you are literally including its text into your C file. This means that including a header with the line `extern int ProgramID = whateverfunctionyouwant();` will declare and define the variable `ProgramID` in each C file.
2. An extern variable needs to be declared wherever it is used, but only defined once. The definition must take the form of a declaration without the `extern` keyword. That will tell the compiler how much storage to allocate for the variable, etc.

To use this information, change your `variable_header.hpp` to only declare an extern, not assign it (be sure to include header guards):

```
#ifndef __VARIABLE_HEADER_HPP__
#define __VARIABLE_HEADER_HPP__
extern int ProgramID;
#endif
```

and modify exactly one source file (say `OGL_Engine.cpp`) to declare the variable globally (in the file but outside of any function, class, struct or namespace):

```
int ProgramID = whateverfunctionyouwant();
```

What your example is missing is a `#include "variable_header.hpp"` in either the C file or the matching header. Assuming that the include is there, the compiler will know that `ProgramID` refers to a name declared elsewhere and will match it to the correct memory location during the linking phase. When the compiler gets to the file that defines the variable, will mark it with the correct symbol regardless of whether it is `extern` or not in that file. This happens to any variable that is declared globally.